# Cannot resolve symbol 'id'

Tags: java, spring

```
//Repository class
package com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.repository;

import com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.model.Post;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

    //Replace with p.userDto.id
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.userDto.id=?1")
    List<Post> findByUserId(Integer userId);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.id IN :users ORDER BY p.createdAt DESC")
    List<Post> findAllPostByUserIds(@Param("users") List<Integer> userIds);

}
```

```
//Entity class
package com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.model;

import com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.dto.UserDto;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String caption;
    private String location;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="user_id")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "email", column = @Column(name="user_email"))
    })
    private UserDto userDto;

    @OneToMany
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
//    @Embedded
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "likedByUsers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<UserDto> likedByUsers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
//User dto
package com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String userImage;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserDto userDto = (UserDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, userDto.id) && Objects.equals(username, userDto.username) && Objects.equals(email, userDto.email) && Objects.equals(name, userDto.name) && Objects.equals(userImage, userDto.userImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, username, email, name, userImage);
    }
}
```

I don't know why the id is unresolved in the repository query even though I have id in userdto. The spring boot api works fine and will run without errors. It's that I'm afraid that this may be causing the problem of images not showing up on my frontend react app. Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, you're using embedded type userDto. You should annotate the class UserDto with Embeddable annotation. Otherwise you can't use it in the queries.

Comment: But in the posts class, the userDto is embedded. Should I also add embedded annotation to the userDto class itself like @Embedded?

Comment: Another annotation: Embeddable. Add it to the UserDto class.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But are there stuff to put inside the @Embeddable like @Embeddable(some stuff here)?  Just curious

Comment: No attributes. Check Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html